# How to load data from a file into a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have a file that has lots of data. I am trying to load the data into a MySQL database.

I have tried using Toad for MySQL but that did not work because I have text in that file that is spread out on more than one line. "example below"

Now I am trying to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` to load the data into a table called tt

But the problem that I am facing is that I get lots of warning. The warning are something like this

```
*************************** 2. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1261
Message: Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
*************************** 3. row ***************************
  Level: Warning
   Code: 1261
Message: Row 1 doesn't contain data for all columns
```

This is the query that I am using

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/RECORDS.dat' INTO TABLE tt FIELDS ENCLOSED BY '|' TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' STARTING BY '006d00000';
```

There is a "|" character between each field. Also the lines always starts with 006d000000 the problem that I am having is because the test has new lines. How can I load this data with no issues?

Here is a sample data out of the file

```
006d000000XXXXXXXX||001d000001CCCCCCCC|DN|Test - Standard|Engaged|New Prospect|10000|||100|Blah Blah|No|FedEx Ground||No|||No|012d0000000wxtFFFFFF|2014-02-10 20:00:32.000000|Test Test|2014-02-24 19:01:46.000000|Bl Test|2014-02-20|||||25.00|Direct|Check|||||Inbound Call||||||||Blah|false|false|false|false|false||false|Merchant||||||||English||||
006d000000YYYYYYYY|12345678912345678|001d000001SvqDDDDD|CS|TEST- Derm|Approved|New Prospect|10000|0|211170101|100|Blah|No|FedEx Ground||No|||No|012d0000000wWWWWWWW|2014-01-30 23:10:10.000000|Mike|2014-03-04 10:26:00.000000|Tester|2014-01-31|Blah1 Blah1  Blah1 Blah1  Blah1 Blah1  
Blah1 Blah1  
Blah1 Blah1  

Blah1 Blah1  
||2014-02-01 00:00:00.000000|2014-01-31|0.00|Direct||||Connie wolf corp office  7322444700 ext 6170|||Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  Blah2 Blah2  
Blah2 Blah2  
Blah2 Blah2  

Blah2 Blah2  

||||SSDFHHDR|false|false|false|false|false||false|Location|||2014-02-03|BBAC||Open||English|Yes|1845000||
```

this is my definition of my tt table

```
CREATE TABLE `tt` (
 `s_id` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `m_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `sf_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `c_name` varchar(68) DEFAULT NULL,
 `stage` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `entype` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `en_amount` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `vm_sales` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ber` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `fansactions` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `prolate` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
 `banocess` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `shipthod` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `averagusage` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `banocessing` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `banesent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `coid` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `siteinoverride` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `record_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `screated_on` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `screated_by` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `smodified_on` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `smodified_by` varchar(52) DEFAULT NULL,
 `submission_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `inside_notes` varchar(283) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `approved_on` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
 `en_process_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `en_fee` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `difeature` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `payment_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `closed_on` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reason_for_cancel` varchar(61) DEFAULT NULL,
 `notes_to_t` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
 `offer_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reschannel` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_notes` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
 `reviewed_td` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `review_tdw` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `date_rtd` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `m_code` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `ref_provider` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `start_up_kit_sent` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `application_source` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did_ancials` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did_iness_license` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did_rk_order` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did_oication` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `did_surance` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `suppon_url` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `interount` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `senments_to` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `last_activity_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_closed_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_created_date` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_contact_name` varchar(54) DEFAULT NULL,
 `change_in_program_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_status` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `f_close_reason` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `language_preference` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `do_you_have_a_signature` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `p_reference_id` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
 `pricing_schedule` varchar(56) DEFAULT NULL,
 `newline` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

How can I fix my query to recognize when the line terminates and also when each field terminates?

Comment: use a macro in an editor like notepad++ to create a uniform data structure

Comment: Randy, how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to change my query to

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'c:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.6/RECORDS.dat' INTO TABLE tt FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '|\n' STARTING BY '';
```